# Firebase Authentication still on Localhost:9099 in Vercel Deployment

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel

I deployed my next.js web app on Vercel which using firestore Authentication, DataBase and Store.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ljgn.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtG6Q.png)

However, I set up the .env file and configuration file, but the web app still GET/POST on localhost:9099
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DIL4.png)

How to solve this problem and make the firebase authentication run?

I tried to change the NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN to Vercel, but the domain still on localhost:9099

Comment: This is most likely the problem with not enabling ‘Sign-in provider’.
Try re-enabling in Firebase Console / Authentication / Sign-in method.

Comment: I tried re-enable the Sign-in method.It's still on localhost:9099